# MAUI Converters throw exceptions

Tags: xaml, maui, maui-community-toolkit

My project has a requirement to add or remove a UI element from the accessibility tree based on if `LeftAccessibilityName` has been set. To achieve this, I have bound `AutomationProperties.IsInAccessibleTree` to the accessibility name and then I use the `IsStringNotNullOrEmpty` converter to get a boolean value. Whenever I try to navigate to the page that contains this control, I get the following navigation exception:

```
Id = 1, Status = RanToCompletion, Method = {null}, Result = NavigationResult { Success = False, Exception = Prism.Navigation.NavigationException: An error occurred while resolving the page. This is most likely the result of invalid XAML or other type initialization exception
 ---> System.Exception: Unable to create Page 'RegistrationUserDetailsPage'.
 ---> Prism.Ioc.ContainerResolutionException: An unexpected error occurred while resolving 'RegistrationUserDetailsPage'
 ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
 ---> System.ArgumentException: targetType needs to be assignable from System.Boolean. (Parameter 'targetType')
```

If I remove the converter, I can navigate to my page with no problems.
I've tried using the more verbose syntax of:

```
<Grid 
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
     xmlns:converters="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
     x:Name="This">
   <Grid.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <converters:IsStringNotNullOrEmptyConverter x:Key="IsStringNotNullOrEmptyConverter"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Grid.Resources>

   <ContentView
        Grid.Column="0"
        AutomationProperties.IsInAccessibleTree="{Binding LeftAccessibilityName, Converter={StaticResource IsStringNotNullOrWhiteSpaceConverter}, Source={x:Reference This}}" />

...
```

But that didn't make any difference.

In my `MauiProgram.cs`, if I initialize the community toolkit like so:
`.UseMauiCommunityToolkit(x => x.SetShouldSuppressExceptionsInConverters(true));`
The problem is also resolved and I can navigate to the page.

**CODE**

```
<Grid
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:converters="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
    x:Name="This"
    ColumnDefinitions="*">

    <ContentView
        Grid.Column="0"
        AutomationProperties.IsInAccessibleTree="{Binding LeftAccessibilityName, Converter={converters:IsStringNotNullOrWhiteSpaceConverter}, Source={x:Reference This}}" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your problem and the IsStringNotNullOrEmptyConverter worked for me. But there is something wrong in your code.

1. In the xaml, **please add the namespace before you declare the converter as the resource**. Such as:

```
<Grid xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:mct="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             >

    <Grid.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <mct:IsStringNotNullOrEmptyConverter x:Key="IsStringNotNullOrEmptyConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Grid.Resources>

</Grid>
```

1. If the `LeftAccessibilityName` is the property in the viewmodel, **please remove the `Source={x:Reference This}` in your binding**, you have bound the property to the `LeftAccessibilityName`. Such as:

```
<Grid
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:components="clr-namespace:Weighter.UI.Components"
    xmlns:converters="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
    x:Name="This"
    ColumnDefinitions="*">

    <ContentView
        Grid.Column="0"
        AutomationProperties.IsInAccessibleTree="{Binding LeftAccessibilityName, Converter={converters:IsStringNotNullOrWhiteSpaceConverter}}" />
</Grid>
```

3. If the `LeftAccessibilityName` is a property of the ContentView or the other control, please change the code about binding. You can check the official doument about [Binding value converters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/converters#binding-value-converters-1).

Comment: 1. I updated my code to include the namespaces. They have been this way the whole time, I just omitted them from the original post.
2. `LeftAccessibilityName` is a `BindableProperty` defined on this component, therefore I need to use the `... Source={x:Reference This}}`
3. I read the linked documentation but I can't find anything that suggests this approach doesn't work. Am I missing something?
4. `IsInAccessibleTree` is a `bool?` as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.automationproperties.isinaccessibletreeproperty?view=net-maui-7.0)

Comment: All right. I can reproduce your problem now. If I changed the IsInAccessibleTree property to the control's property such as IsEnable or IsVisible, the binding will work. Or if I removed the converter and bind the IsInAccessibleTree property to a bool variable, the binding will work too. But when the value converter is used in the binding of the  IsInAccessibleTree property. The app will be broken. You can post it as an new issue for the [maui community toolkit on the github](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/issues). @BruceTheBrick

Comment: Ah, damn! Thanks for the assistance with testing! Guess I'll submit an issue